# sending data to other android device by skiller

Tags: android, multiplayer

I'm trying to make a multiplayer game using Skiller SDK for android platform.
I need to send some data from the creator to the other player.
I attempt to do this by sending the data in the game settings string and receive it from the other device and process it.
The thing is when i do this, only 50 chars of my string are sent and the other chars are not sent.
So my question is does the games settings String allows only 50 chars to be sent ????
And how to send this in the start of the game?
Please provide me with some code samples.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We updated the description and settings strings to max length of 250 chars.
Please test your game again.

For more info please check our wiki pages: [wiki.skiller-games.com](http://wiki.skiller-games.com)